# Construct Ellipses and Ellipsoids in MATLAB from MATRICES

Tags: matlab, ellipse

Can some one explain how to draw ellipses and ellipsoids in MATLAB for two cases: Viz, for square and non-square matrices.

Case 1) `A = [25 28 31; 27 26 29; 30 27 28];`

Case 2) `B = [25 28 31; 27 26 29; 30 27 28; 29 27 38; 31 25 29];`

Furthermore, how to calculate semi-axis length (i.e.xr, yr, and zr) of a given matrix for following MATLAB function. I know xc, yc, and zc are the mean for respective columns (i.e. x, y, and z) of the matrix.

```
[x,y,z] = ellipsoid(xc,yc,zc,xr,yr,zr,n)
```

Pleae note that I am new to both Quadric shapes and MATLAB, so please give more descriptive and detailed answer! Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drawing an ellipse given the covariance matrix `C`:

```
th = linspace(0, 2*pi, 500 );
xy = [cos(th);sin(th)];
RR = chol( C ); % cholesky decomposition
exy = xy'*RR; %//'
figure;
plot( 2*exy(:,1)+mx, 2*exy(:,2)+my, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2 );
```